# CSS set display block to parent <ul> if <li> has class active

Tags: css

I have simple question regarding CSS parent and child.

Now I need the sub menu show when one of menu has class `active`.

I know we just can add `display: block` together with `sub-menu`. But I need when one of menu has class active the `ul` will be set to `display: block`.

Is it possible?

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu .active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>A</li>
    <li class="active">B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
</ul>

<ul class="menu">
  <li>Menu 2</li>
  
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Are  you trying to make an accordion? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Comment: Try the CSS :has() pseudo class

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<ul>` can not be the child of a `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are we trying to hide? The .menu with or without the .active elem or the submenu with or without the .active?

If you are looking to have one active sub-menu then using the :has() pseudo-selector should do it.

```css
.menu {
  list-style: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu:has(.active) {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu .active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Menu 1</li>

  <li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>A</li>
      <li class="active">B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu">
  <li>Menu 2</li>

  <li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Please delete this and fix the HTML. A `<ul>` cannot be the child of a `<ul>`